# MS Excel formula for copying links

Tags: microsoft-excel

How to make formula which works like this:

```
Taking data form one sheet above and one from the right against the selected one.
```

So, it should be as shown on the picture:

[image]

G3 is equal to "=C3", H3 should be equal to "C+1 3+1" and I3 should be "D+1 4+1".

Is is possible to manage somehow without macros or how to configure macro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `INDIRECT` and `ADDRESS` function, together with the `ROW` and `COLUMN` function. I don't know how you want to define the first cell (in this case C3), but this should work:

On cell H3,

```
=INDIRECT(ADRESS(ROW($C$3)+1;COLUMN($C$3)+1))
```

On cell I3,

```
=INDIRECT(ADRESS(ROW($C$3)+2;COLUMN($C$3)+2))
```

And so on. If you put the numbers 1, 2 etc in Row 2, then you can write down the formulas in cell G3 as:

```
=INDIRECT(ADRESS(ROW($C$3)+G$2;COLUMN($C$3)+G$2))
```

And when copying that to the other columns, it should work properly on the references, since we will work with relative references. It should look like this:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `OFFSET` for that:
`=OFFSET($C$3,COLUMN(G3)-COLUMN($G$3),COLUMN(G3)-COLUMN($G$3))`

[image]